# Partial derivative chain rule problem

Tags: partial-derivative

Suppose $f(x,y,z)$ is a function, where $z$ is a function of $x,y$, i.e. $z=u(x,y)$. Does the following hold due to the chain rule?

> $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x,y,u(x,y))=\frac{\partial }{\partial
>  x}f(x,y,u(x,y))+\frac{\partial }{\partial
>  u}f(x,y,u(x,y))\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$$

I dont think this is true because if so then $\frac{\partial }{\partial
 u}f(x,y,u(x,y))\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ should be $0$?

Answer (score 0):

you can't get ∂ from your function beacuse with change in x then z change too, so you should use defferential

> ${d\over
> dx}$f(x,y,u(x,y))=${∂\over∂x}$f(x,y,u(x,y))+${∂\over∂u}$f(x,y,u(x,y))${∂u\over∂x}$

chain rule definition [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule)

=================================================

You problem will become clearer if you note :

> ${∂f(x,y,z(x,y))\over∂x}$=${∂f\over∂x′}$(x,y,z(x,y))${∂x\over∂x}$+${∂f\over∂y′}$
>   (x,y,z(x,y))${∂y\over∂x}$+${∂f\over∂z′}$(x,y,z(x,y))${∂z\over∂x}$.

Indeed, you are not differentiating among the same variables : writting f(x,y,z(x,y))=f∘g(x,y) with g(x,y)=(x,y,z(x,y)),and so (x,y)↦(x,y,z(x,y))↦f(x,y,z(x,y)),then x
 is the first variable in the source of g
 (i.e. ℝ2) while x′
is the first variable in the source of  f
 (i.e. ℝ3).

this anwer is here  [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548014/confusing-use-of-the-chain-rule)

and a question that can help you [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981316/chain-rule-for-multiple-variables)

Comment: view $g(x,y)=f(x,y,u(x,y))$, then what should be $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$? I am confused with these operations

Comment: @Nick Liu ${∂g\over∂x}$ that is PARTIAL DERIVATIVES z=f(x,y) the partial derivative with respect to x is just the ordinary derivative of the function of a
single variable that we get by keeping y fixed, but chain rule is result of differentiable function .if we have a z=F(u,v) u=$\varphi$(x,y) , v=$\phi$(x,y) then we have ${∂z\over∂x}$=${∂f\over∂u}$${∂u\over∂x}$+${∂f\over∂v}$${∂v\over∂x}$ and similarly for y

Comment: but in this form we have  two function with x,y variable and we can change x when y is fixed and then our function is just on x,but in your question we can't do change in x when other variable take fixed

Comment: i'm sorry for my english language mistakes .i hope it can help you